# VS2017 MYSQL SQLDataSource - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database, sqldatasource, connector

So, I am trying to run a query using SQLDataSource on VS with MYSQL, and whatever the query is, I get the same error which is **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**. 
The SQLDataSource is already connected to the database, so there is nothing wrong with my connection string.

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="helbotelConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=helbotel;User Id=root;password=MYPASSWORD"
      providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.10.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**SQLDataSource**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlNews" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:helbotelConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:helbotelConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * from users"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Error Page**
[Error page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVIp8.jpg)

P.S: I already use mysql connections from backcode and they work perfectly but this problem only occurs with SQLDataSource (I need it for GridView)

Comment: This error is caused when you bind the datasource to something.  Please add what you are binding (and how you are binding it) since that seems to be involved with the problem.

Comment: I did not get to the datasource binding yet, I am trying to run the query from the SQLDatasource query test and its not working, ive tried binding it with a gridview and it displayed the error on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

[Issue with MySQL for Visual Studio / Visual Studio 2017 Datasource Wizard. Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48582096/issue-with-mysql-for-visual-studio-visual-studio-2017-datasource-wizard-objec)

I had the same issue, the following resolved it:

- Uninstalled MySQL for Visual Studio
- Uninstalled MySQL Connector/Net
- Re-Installed Latest Version for MySQL for Visual Studio
- Installed Previous Version for MySQL Connector/Net (6.9.11)
- Downgraded MySQL.Data to 6.9.11
- Downgraded MySQL.Web to 6.9.11

There appears to be an issue with the latest version of Connector/NET.

I have posted this as a MySQL Connector/NET Bug.

Comment: I just ran into this exact same problem, just with MySql 6.10.6 rather than 6.10.5. I was thrown through the wringer until i came across this thread. I downgraded to 6.9.11 and that resolved the issue. I also have Visual Studio 2011. Any update/cure yet and why that happens?

Comment: Your answer does not have the link to the MySQL Connector/NET bug report, so that others can follow.