# Issue with MySQL for Visual Studio / Visual Studio 2017 Datasource Wizard. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Windows 10 Pro
Visual Studio 2017 Pro - 15.5.6
MySQL for Visual Studio - 1.2.7
MySQL Connector/NET - 6.10.6.0

I have encountered an issue with MySQL for Visual Studio.

When opening the 'Configuring a Data Source' dialog box, and adding a query, I can query the data fine.

[image]

When running the Test Query on the final screen, it fails with the following error:

[image]

When finishing the configuration without testing the query, and subsequently running the debug - an Object Reference exception is thrown as shown below:

[image]

I have tested this on other solutions that previously worked, but I am getting the same issue.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. For anyone who is interested - I did the following:

- Uninstalled MySQL for Visual Studio
- Uninstalled MySQL Connector/Net
- Re-Installed Latest Version for MySQL for Visual Studio
- Installed Previous Version for MySQL Connector/Net (6.9.11)
- Downgraded MySQL.Data to 6.9.11
- Downgraded MySQL.Web to 6.9.11

There appears to be an issue with the latest version of Connector/NET.

I have posted this as a MySQL Connector/NET Bug.

Answer (score 0):

This also occurs in VS2015 using anything over MYSQL for VS 1.2.4 and Connector/NET 6.9.8. When VS2017 was first released it worked with MYSQL but it breaks after making any changes to the MYSQL components, e.g upgrading to the latest GA release. I cannot remember the original configuration for the working VS2017. I have tried all combinations of MYSQL for VS and connectors but nothing has worked. Eventually I went back to 2015 because 1.2.4 does not support 2017. (Tried on both Windows 10 Home and Professional)
I suppose my answer is downgrade to VS2015, which is not really a fix.

Comment: Hi Rob, sorry this is 6 months late - but i've found installing MySQL Data through NuGet and downgrading the installation to 6.9.11 resolved all of the above regarding VS2017.