# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when adding a table adapter

Tags: visual-studio, mysql-connector, wizard, tableadapter

I successfully connected to my database, however I am not able to add a TableAdapter. Using TableAdapter Configuration Wizard I can use the query builder and everything seems fine, I can see the tables, retrieve the rows, everything. however when I am trying to finish the configuration I get the title error. What should I do? thank you

[image: the error]

This is what I Have in my VS

[image: This is what I Have in my VS]

I am using MySql and C#.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: i don't think it's the same question

Comment: It is the same :) Your error message is the same as the duplicated question. Check the content of the question.

Comment: it's the same error but it doesn't appear in the same context

Comment: The accepted answer there explains how to debug that even if it is not the same context and a lot of examples about different technologies.

Comment: @A.Dravid, FYI here in Stackoverflow the suggested answer is used as a catch-all for any question raising NullReferenceException. The idea is that it should be easy to debug after you know an object somewhere is null. However you're getting this exception when using a wizard. Do you have access to the code causing the exception?

Comment: it is possible that you don't have correct MySQL driver version for .Net connector, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48099305/vs2017-mysql-sqldatasource-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-objec

Comment: it doesn't work sadly :( i did exactly what he said trying multiple versions

Comment: @CodeNotFound The NullReferenceException isn't coming from the OP's code but from the (buggy) MySQL VS addin they're trying to use; it's not possible to debug it using the steps in that answer.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger yep maybe. That is what it is « possible duplicate » not « exact duplicate ». Also it exists many answers there. The accepted answer can’t be always the right one. I think You can also add your answer there if you want or let it here also.

Comment: I have the same problem and probably is a bug of MySQL Visual Studio addin like suggested by @BradleyGrainger

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in the MySQL Visual Studio addin: [bug 90390](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90390).

If you create an account at bugs.mysql.com you can click the **Subscribe** button on that bug report to get updates (e.g., when an updated version is released that fixes the bug).

Comment: Is this a visual studio bug or is it a bug on the connectors?

Comment: @MbaiMburu It's a bug in the MySQL addin.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Visual studio 2019.

1. Close visual studio and uninstall MySQL for visual studio along with any Connector/NET you might have
2. Install MySQL for visual studio 1.2.10.
3. Now install Connector to avoid factory errors [connector factory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQroa.png)
   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQroa.png): https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8b4be4b0-d687-4f0c-b690-9ae47ff06411/cannot-obtain-provider-factory-for-mysqldatamysqlclient?forum=visualstudiogeneral Ensure you install Connector/NET version that matches what's in your system. Mine is Connector/NET 6.10.7
4. Start visual studio and this time you'll see an update pop-up, accept the update and restart visual studio once it completes.
5. [image: Done & dusted]